# Pandas - Groupby dataframe store as dataframe without aggregating

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I'm new to Pandas and I've read a lot of documentation, posts and answers here but I've been unable to discern a good strategy to approach my goal, sorry if its already answered, I couldn't find it. Here is what I have:

```
df = {'key': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B'], 'value': [2,2,1,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df
   key  value
0   A   2
1   B   2
2   A   1
3   B   1
```

I know that doing `groupby()` would return a groupby object, and I know that I can do a lot of aggregating stuff (count, size, mean, etc) using the groupby object. However, I don't want to aggregate, I just want to groupby my dataframe based on 'key' column and store it as a dataframe like the following:

```
   key  value
0   A   2
1   A   1
2   B   2
3   B   1
```

Once I get this step done, what I eventually want is to order each group by value like the following:

```
   key  value
0   A   1
1   A   2
2   B   1
3   B   2
```

Any answer, comment, or hint is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: a `groupby` object is just metadata describing how to perform the grouping it is not a df, it returns a series or a df when you perform some kind of aggregation on the `groupby` object it doesn't make sense to try to store this

Comment: OK, I mentioned in my question that groupby is an object, any hint or solution then? Because the sort that is suggested below is not what I'm looking for. I want to keep the order of occurrence of rows in my table whereas sort strictly sorts them based on string order.

Answer (score 10):

You can get your desired output by sorting your dataframe with [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) instead of doing a `groupby`.

```
df.sort_values(['key', 'value'], inplace=True)
```

Edit:

If you really want to use `groupby` to perform the grouping of the keys, so could apply a trivial `filter` to the `groupby` object.

```
df = df.groupby('key').filter(lambda x: True)
```

This doesn't seem like the best way to get a dataframe back, but nothing else immediately comes to mind.  Afterwards you'd still need to use `sort_values` to order the values column.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the reason I want to use groupby is: 1- I want to figure out if there is a way using groupby. 2- Using sort is not exactly what I want because it sorts either based on string (alpha) or numeric (values), right? Rather, I want to group by keys no matter their position in alphabets, and/or numbers, rather their occurrence in the table.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a method using `groupby`.

Comment: Thanks @root! but that doesn't seem to be working, the df doesn't change after executing the line in your edit, or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to do it without using chaining then this should work...

```
df = {'key': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B'], 'value': [2,2,1,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

groups = df.groupby(['key', 'value'])
groups = sorted(groups)
df = pd.concat([g for _, g in groups])

print(df)
```

For the record, I don't fully understand why you wouldn't sort the entire frame... I am guessing that you need groups for other transformations besides sorting anyway, and so you want to save yourself from having to sort the entire frame.  If you found better performance by doing this then please let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

If the reason you want to use `groupby` is to preserve the index structure then you can do the following:

```
df = {'key': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B'], 'value': [2,2,1,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
print(df) 

key  value
0   A      2
1   B      2
2   A      1
3   B      1
```

So, first create the index:

```
df.set_index(['key'], inplace=True)
print(df)

     value
key       
A        2
B        2
A        1
B        1
```

Then, sort the index:

```
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
print(df)

     value
key       
A        2
A        1
B        2
B        1
```

Then, sort the values:

```
df.sort_values('value',inplace=True)
print(df)

     value
key       
A        1
B        1
A        2
B        2
```

And if you want to preserve the original index, finally do:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
print(df)

  key  value
0   A      1
1   B      1
2   A      2
3   B      2
```