# Output and preserve groupby index structure without aggregate function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that I want to groupby year and followed by months within each year. Due to the fact that the data are quite huge (recorded from 3 decades ago till now), I would like to have the output presented as shown below for subsequent calculation but without any aggregate function such ".mean()" behind.

However, I am unable to do so because groupby always require an .agg, else it will show this error: <pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x0000022BF79A52E0>

On the other hand, I am a bit worried about importing as Series because I do not know how to set the parameters to get exactly the same format as below. Another reason is that I used the below lines to import the .csv into dataframe:

```
df=pd.read_csv(r'file directory', index_col = 'date')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

For some weird reasons, if I define the date string format in pd.read_csv to import and subsequently, try to sort by other methods according to years and month, function or method that gets confused when the records have date starts off with 01(day)/01(month)/1990 and 01(day)/02(month)/1990. For example, it interprets the first number in Jan as day and the second number as month and sorts all chronologically but when it comes to Feb, when the day is should be 01, the method thought that 01 is the month and 02 is the day portion and move that Feb record to the Jan group.

Are there any ways to achieve the same format?

Methods shown in the post below does not seem to help me get the format I want: [Pandas - Groupby dataframe store as dataframe without aggregating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36069373/pandas-groupby-dataframe-store-as-dataframe-without-aggregating)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC:

You can use `dayfirst` parameter in `to_datetime()` and set that equal to `True` then create 'Year' and 'Month' column and make them index and sort index:

```
df=pd.read_csv(r'file directory')
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'],dayfirst=True)
df['Year']=df['date'].dt.year
df['Month']=df['date'].dt.month
df=df.set_index(['Year','Month']).sort_index()
```

OR in 3 steps via `assign()`:

```
df=pd.read_csv(r'file directory')
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'],dayfirst=True)
df=(df.assign(Year=df['date'].dt.year,Month=df['date'].dt.month)
      .set_index(['Year','Month']).sort_index())
```

Comment: Hi Anurag, for both methods, they don't work because it returns Keyerror 'date'.

Comment: @user14074078 replace that 'date' with the column that have date like values in your actual dataset...here 'date' is placeholder for datelike column

Comment: I discover the issue, my read_csv has an argument index_col = 'date'. After deleting that part, your code works. I have modified your code a bit to include day since I realise that my subsequent processing needs it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate through the groups of the `groupby` results.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
rand = np.random.RandomState(1)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['foo', 'bar'] * 3,
                   'B': rand.randn(6),
                   'C': rand.randint(0, 20, 6)})
groupby_obj = df.groupby(['A'])

for k, gdf in groupby_obj:
    print('Groupby Key:', k)
    print('Dataframe:\n', gdf, '\n')
```

you can apply all dataframe methods on `gdf`

Comment: Hi Asrst, I did a df.index.values after importing and I am shown the below output: array(['1990-01-01', '1990-01-02', '1990-01-03', ..., '2020-12-29', '2020-12-30', '2020-12-31']

Also, my groupby don't allow me to assign it without a method attached behind.